# How can I get my code running 24/7 on replit without it only working once and then my bot also not working?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, replit

I made code for my discord bot and used UptimeRobot to keep it running constantly but then it my bot just stopped working randomly and I'm not sure why. It worked once and maybe ran for a few hours and now it completely won't work, even if I get rid of the 'keep_alive' code.

UptimeRobot - https://uptimerobot.com Discord Bot Tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SPTfmiYiuok | Time - 58:47

Main:

[Start of code]

```
import os
import random
import discord
from keep_alive import keep_alive
```

[ALL MY CODE/COMMANDS]

Then at the end of is this [my commands] ---->

```
keep_alive()
my_secret = os.environ['TOKEN']
client.run[my_secret]
```

[NEW FILE-KEEP_ALIVE.PY]

```
from flask import Flask
from threading import Thread

app = Flask('')

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return "Hello. I am alive!"

def run():
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=8080)

def keep_alive():
    t = Thread(target=run)
    t.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use free hosting services, they are usually really bad. You should get a paid one (you not need to spend money on it and get premium servers) you can try amazon aws free trail. it should be enough for the discord bot and run 24/7 for 12 months. Other than that, if you need more ressouces you can find a hosting provider, register with a virtual creditcard, order the stuff you like and freeze the vcc. a good vcc provider is revolut.